# Bash Completion not working at second argument

Tags: kubectl

On Mac OSX Mojave, kubectl tab completion with bash and zsh partially works.

By partially, I mean the following:

Tab completion works after kubectl command (get, exec,...) but doesn't work at the 2nd argument (eg: kubectl get  doesn't show any additional option)

I've ensured following command is run before: source <(kubectl completion bash)

Any hint ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is everything fine with your connection to the cluster? does `kubectl get pods` return the list of pods?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for the update. Indeed it looked like I had some connectivity issue with my cluster. After resetting the .kube/config file now tab completion works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luca Brasi commented, the connectivity issue has been solved after resetting .kube/config file.